# Vue Tables 2 with Slots. How to pass data id to event handler?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-tables-2

I'm using a slot to display a button in Vue Tables 2.  How can I pass the id of the warehouse i.e. 123 or 456 to the edit() event handler?

I've tried adding props (as this is what the docs show). But I haven't had any luck. I'm using Vue Tables 2 in a component.

```
<template>
<div>
    <h1>How to pass warehouse id to edit() method?</h1>
    <v-client-table :columns="columns" :data="warehouses" :options="options">
        <span slot="actions" slot-scope="{ WarehousesMin }"> 
            <button v-on:click="edit">Edit</button>
        </span>
    </v-client-table>
</div>
```

```
export default { 
name: 'WarehousesMin',
 data() {
        return {
            warehouses: [
                {"id": 123, "name": "El Dorado", "loc": "EDO"},
                {"id": 456, "name": "Tartarus", "loc": "TAR"}
            ],
            options: {
                headings: {name: 'Name', code: 'Loc', actions: 'Actions'}
            },
            columns: ['name', 'loc', 'actions'],
        }
    },
methods: {
    edit (warehouseId) {
        // How to get id of warehouse here?  i.e. 123 or 456
    }   
   }
}
```

Comment: check [Vue-table-2 Guide: scoped-slots](https://github.com/matfish2/vue-tables-2#scoped-slots), it provides one similar sample as yours.

Comment: try this ` <button v-on:click="edit(props.row.id)">Edit</button>`

Comment: Thanks Sphinx, boussadjra. Setting slot-scope="props" and passing the id with  <button v-on:click="edit(props.row.id)">Edit</button> works.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't used this library before, but as far as I know about Vue slots, you can change your code into this and try again:

```
<template>
<div>
    <h1>How to pass warehouse id to edit() method?</h1>
    <v-client-table :columns="columns" :data="warehouses" :options="options">
        <span slot="actions" slot-scope="{row}"> 
            <button v-on:click="edit(row.id)">Edit</button>
        </span>
    </v-client-table>
</div>
```

and in script part, change to:

```
export default { 
name: 'WarehousesMin',
 data() {
        return {
            warehouses: [
                {"id": 123, "name": "El Dorado", "loc": "EDO"},
                {"id": 456, "name": "Tartarus", "loc": "TAR"}
            ],
            options: {
                headings: {name: 'Name', code: 'Loc', actions: 'Actions'}
            },
            columns: ['id', 'name', 'loc', 'actions'],
        }
    },
methods: {
    edit (warehouseId) {
        // The id can be fetched from the slot-scope row object when id is in columns
    }   
   }
}
```

I think this ought to work, but if not please let me know.